# javascript set drop down options throws cannot read getAttribute error

Tags: javascript

I am having some weird behavior with a script I made to submit reports. The script clicks a generate new button which launches a window. Within that window, these three drop downs are visible.

```
var lastOneYear = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Last one year"]')[0];
var catalogs = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Select All"]')[0];
var enrollment = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Select All"]')[1];
```

I can do this to set the drop-down values I want without any issues

```
var lastOneYear = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Last one year"]')[0];
var catalogs = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Select All"]')[0];
var enrollment = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Select All"]')[1];
        
if(lastOneYear.getAttribute("aria-selected") != 'true') lastOneYear.click();
if(catalogs.getAttribute("aria-selected") != 'true') catalogs.click();
if(enrollment.getAttribute("aria-selected") != 'true') enrollment.click();
```

Next, below these drop downs there is an Advanced link that expands the window to show this drop down which has several options I need to select.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Select All"]')[2]
```

When I attempt to do this I get an error

```
VM9253:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute')
```

Regardless of whether or not the advanced link has been pressed, within the console window I can do this without any issues.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Select All"]')[2].getAttribute("aria-selected")
//returns either a true or false
```

I can also do something like this

```
var lvl3 = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Level_3"]')[0];
if(lvl3.getAttribute("aria-selected") != 'true') lvl3.click();
```

I thought maybe it had something to do with the drop-down being hidden, so I added an extra step to expand which also works just fine.

```
var advanced = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="announcement-advancedSettings"]')[0];
advanced.click();
```

I tried adding a timer to make a delay, but that seems to not wait for completion

```
function wait(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, time);
    });
}
```

Despite within my test function I "await wait(30000);" before proceeding. It seems to just fire off everything at once. When I expand the Promise within the console, I get that the status is pending.
As soon as I attempt to run my full test script it breaks and I don’t understand why. I can execute in the console each line one by one, but the second I try and make a function and call it everything breaks. Am I missing something?

```
function wait(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, time);
    });
}

async function test()
{

    var fin = false;
    
    
    while(!fin)
    {
    
        if(document.querySelectorAll('[validationid="controller:learner-transcript-details:::svg:::queue"]').length == 0)
        {
        
            document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="learner-transcript"]')[0].click();
            
            var lastOneYear = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Last one year"]')[0];
            var catalogs = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Select All"]')[0];
            var enrollment = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Select All"]')[1];
                        
            if(lastOneYear.getAttribute("aria-selected") != 'true') lastOneYear.click();
            if(catalogs.getAttribute("aria-selected") != 'true') catalogs.click();
            if(enrollment.getAttribute("aria-selected") != 'true') enrollment.click();
            
            var advanced = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="announcement-advancedSettings"]')[0];
            advanced.click();
            
            await wait(30000);
            
            // All drop downs above are selected properly and the advanced tab is open with the drop down containing these items to select is visible but it errors here
            if(document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Select All"]')[2].getAttribute("aria-selected") == 'true') document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Select All"]')[2].click();
            if(document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Deadline (UTC TimeZone)"]')[0].getAttribute("aria-selected") != 'true') document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Deadline (UTC TimeZone)"]')[0].click();
    
        
            
            
            fin = 'true'
        }
        else await wait(5000);
    }
}
```

Edit: worth noting is that regardless of the advanced link being clicked or not expanding the rest of the window, I can do this is the console no matter what and it doesnt error.

```
var lvl3 = document.querySelectorAll('[automationid="Level_3"]')[0];
if(lvl3.getAttribute("aria-selected") != 'true') lvl3.click();
```

I also tried changing the wait function to async without any success

```
async function wait(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, time);
    });
}

async function test(){...}
```